# Wiring receptacles to light switch

Tags: wiring

I am wanting to install 4 receptacles that are controlled by a switch.  I am running 12/2 wire lights are (4) 4 ft led lights this is all that will be plugged into the receptacles. The breaker box is at back of shop so wire will run from back of shop to front door where light switch will be. Using 12/2 wire can this be done or would I have to run aditional wire.

Comment: You might want to run 12/3 just so you have the option of each receptacle having always on _and_ switched power.

Comment: Those LED fixtures use like 15 watts each for a grand total of 60 watts.  If you want the wiring to be easier to work with and won't be putting in any other loads, go ahead and use 14/2 wire.  Be sure to use a 15 amp breaker for it though.

Answer (score 1):

If you take one long 12/2 wire directly from the source to the switch and then connect from there to every receptacle, then it can all be done with 12/2. However, if you plan to take the wire from the breaker to an outlet first and then eventually the switch, you'd have to run 12/3 between everything but to the breaker and wire nut the hot together all the way until the switch.

You can do this all with 12/2.

Answer (score 0):

You can get away with running 12/2 and accomplish what you want to.  Depending on the voltage current requirements of the lighting fixtures you might even be able to get away with 14/2.  The biggest problem (as long as the lights don't draw more than 10-15 amps) is the voltage drop that can happen over long runs of wire.

If you've already got the 12/2, go with it.  It will work.

Here's a quick diagram of how I would wire this up.  Please forgive my childish sketches - MS Word was the only program I have available to draw in right now.

[image: Wiring Diagram]

Note though, as someone else said in the comments, that the way this is wired, switching off the light switch would kill all power to the outlets.  Save yourself some money and don't bother installing outlets if you can direct wire the lights (instead of plugging them into the outlets). Depending on the type of enclosure that the lights are in, you might be able to utilize the enclosures as junction boxes themselves.

Hope this helps.

Comment: My thought was you could go from the breaker box and run black straight to light switch but the white go in one side of plugin then connect white to other side of plugin then it would go to the other plugin and continue like that for other two receptacles then take the black to the switch and the white from the plugin to switch. That's what the old Time Life book shows anyway lol would that work. If that is confusing you ill try to get it drawn out.

Comment: There are a number of ways in which you could feasibly wire the circuit, and what you're trying to describe could possibly work, but I'm struggling a little to understand your description. A sketch would be helpful.